# Java - Gif Resizing

Tags: java, resize, gif

i am resizing images with this function :

```
static ImageIcon ChangeSize(String path, int width, int hight){
    ImageIcon Icon = new ImageIcon(path);
    Image image = Icon.getImage();
    Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(width, hight,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    Icon = new ImageIcon(newimg);
    return Icon;
}
```

is there any simple way to resize a gif in a similar way?

Comment: Try `Image.SCALE_DEFAULT`.

Comment: @teppic thanks it is working now :D